# Making newtype instance of Ord Class

Tags: haskell

Since Ord is a Subclass of Eq I find it difficult to understand how making a newtype instance of that class will look like.

I have managed to do this:

```
    newtype NT1 = NT1 Integer

    instance Eq NT1 where 
        (NT1 x) == (NT1 y) = x == y 

    instance Ord NT1 where 
        (NT1 x) `compare` (NT1 y) = x `compare` y
```

If I for examle have a variable `x = NT1 5` and variable `y = NT1 5` and type x == y it will return `True`

I managed also to do this:

```
instance Show NT1 where
        show (NT1 n) = show n
```

whill display `x = NT1 5` as `5` instead of `NT1 5`

following this I should be able to do something like this:

```
instance Ord NT1 where 
       (>)  (NT1 x)(NT1 y)  =  (NT1 x) >   (NT1 y)
       (<)  (NT1 x)(NT1 y)  =  (NT1 x) <   (NT1 y)
       (<=) (NT1 x)(NT1 y)  =  (NT1 x) <=  (NT1 y)
       (>=) (NT1 x)(NT1 y)  =  (NT1 x) >=  (NT1 y)
```

But this doesn't work. How do I do this with Ord class :

```
class  (Eq a) => Ord a  where
    compare              :: a -> a -> Ordering
    (<), (<=), (>=), (>) :: a -> a -> Bool
    max, min             :: a -> a -> a
```

?

Comment: Note that in the cases where it works you don’t have `NT` on the right-hand side of the equation.

Comment: I'm confused. You say "I should be able to do something like this", and then post code which defines an operation in terms of itself. Why would you expect that to work? Did you mean to just have eg. `x > y` on the right-hand-side insteiad of the versions wrapped in `NT1`?

Comment: I've rolled your post back to an earlier version. Please don't make large edits to your question to change what code you're asking for help with. If you've found an answer in the comments, then post that as an answer yourself; or if you've gotten over your current hurdle and have a new question, then post that as a new, separate question.

Comment: @amalloy I acctually added the addition to my question at the beginning of the post and left original question under that and marked it with ***Original Question*** I can't understand what was the problem? Why should I have posted it as an answer when I wasn't sure if it was correct myself?

Comment: @cheshire Indeed, I saw the old content was still there - thanks for trying to make sure you don't delete useful content. But it's still quite confusing to have the first thing a reader sees be an "update" to the following text, which they haven't even read yet! They'd have to scroll past your update, read the original post, go back to your update, and try to mentally piece it all together. Better to just post your candidate solution as an answer, even if you don't know it's right. Lots of wrong answers are posted on Stack Overflow every day, and an answer makes room for votes/comments.

Comment: @amalloy ok thanks, will be more careful next time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> following this I should be able to do something like this:
>
> ```
> instance Ord NT1 where 
>        (>)  (NT1 x)(NT1 y)  =  (NT1 x) >   (NT1 y)
>        (<)  (NT1 x)(NT1 y)  =  (NT1 x) <   (NT1 y)
>        (<=) (NT1 x)(NT1 y)  =  (NT1 x) <=  (NT1 y)
>        (>=) (NT1 x)(NT1 y)  =  (NT1 x) >=  (NT1 y)
> ```

What you here do is basically defining a set of functions where each function calls itself, with the *same* parameters, so this will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Indeed, here for example you define:

> ```
> instance Ord NT1 where 
>        (>)  (NT1 x)(NT1 y)  =  (NT1 x) >   (NT1 y)
> ```

so that means that you say `NT1 x > NT1 y`, given `NT1 x > NT1 y`, but of course that does not really do anything.

The nice thing is that you do not need to define all these functions: Haskell has constructed already a lot of other functions in the `Ord` typeclass in terms of others, so if we take a look at the [documentation for `Ord`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Ord), we see:

> **Minimal complete definition**
>
> ```
> compare | (<=)
> ```

So implementing `compare`, or `(<=)` is sufficient. Haskell can, based on that implementation, also calculate the other comparisons, as well as `min`, `max`, etc. You *can* implement these, if for example there are more efficient ways to check if `NT1 x < NT1 y` than calling `compare` and checking if the result is `LT`.

Your implementation like:

> ```
> newtype NT1 = NT1 Integer
>
> instance Eq NT1 where 
>     (NT1 x) == (NT1 y) = x == y 
>
> instance Ord NT1 where 
>     (NT1 x) `compare` (NT1 y) = x `compare` y
> ```

is thus sufficient, for example:

```
Prelude> NT1 14 < NT1 25
True
```

thus compares the two objects correctly.

This is also a straightforward implementation, the fact that two `NT1` objects are equal if the constructors are the same (well here there is only *one* constructor), and the arguments is a straightforward implementation.

`Ord` has also a "popular" implementation: an object is considered smaller than another object given that the constructor of the first object is defined before the constructor of the second object, or if the constructors are the same, that the arguments are smaller by comparing these "lexicographically".

Haskell has support for these kind of implementations, you can use a `deriving` clause in your type definition:

```
newtype NT1 = NT1 Integer deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

Here we thus "automatically" implement the `Eq`, `Ord` and `Show` typeclass. For `Show` it is implemented by first showing the name of the constructor followed by the `show` of the arguments. It also adds brackets in some cases where it is ambiguous (although the rules are a bit more complex).

We can also, like [@DanielWagner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53270609/making-newtype-instance-of-ord-class/53270747?noredirect=1#comment93425410_53270747) implement these functions ourself, with:

```
instance Ord NT1 where 
    compare (NT1 x) (NT1 y) = compare x y
    (>)  (NT1 x)(NT1 y)  = x > y
```

Here we thus do *not* call this with `NT1` data constructors on the right side, since otherwise we would simply call this function again with the same parameters. With the above implementation, we call `x > y`, so `(>)` but on the *arguments* wrapped in the constructor.

Comment: ...and if you really want to implement all the `Ord` methods yourself for whatever reason, you can `(>) (NT x) (NT y) = (>) x y` (no `NT` wrappers on the right). Or, using infix notation the way it was intended, `NT x > NT y = x > y`.

Comment: @DanielWagner: indeed, after rereading, that was missing, thanks :)